# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function insertUserDetails() in /Volumes/Datas/Sites/dev/sicgaboma/includes/classes/Account.inc.php:25

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I'm currently following a set of video tutorials on login form that store data int mysql db. I am able to connect to the database, but when calling this private function to insert the userDetails:

```
        private function insertUserDetails($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $passwd) {

        $encryptedPasswd = md5($passwd);
        $profilePic = "assets/img/profile-pics/profile_pic.pgn";
        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        $result = mysqli_query($this->connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$uname', '$fname', '$lname', '$eml', '$encryptedPasswd', '$date', '$profilePic')");

        return $result;
    }
```

here

```
        public function register($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $cemail, $passwd, $cpasswd) {

        $this->validateUsername($uname);
        $this->validateFirstname($fname);
        $this->validateLastname($lname);
        $this->validateEmail($eml, $cemail);
        $this->validatePasswords($passwd, $cpasswd);

        if(empty($this->errorArray) == true) {// Check if array contain errors, if not insert data into db
            return insertUserDetails($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $passwd);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function insertUserDetails() in /Volumes/Datas/Sites/dev/sicgaboma/includes/classes/Account.inc.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /Volumes/Datas/Sites/dev/sicgaboma/includes/handlers/register-handler.php(35): Account->register('testUser', 'John', 'Doe', 'Johndoe@test.co...', 'Johndoe@test.co...', '1234567', '1234567') #1 /Volumes/Datas/Sites/dev/sicgaboma/register.php(11): include('/Volumes/Datas/...') #2 {main} thrown in /Volumes/Datas/Sites/dev/sicgaboma/includes/classes/Account.inc.php on line 25

The error is related to the call of the function register() in register-handler.php.

When I set the return to TRUE there no error message.

the code use a function __construct to connect to sql.

Here is the code so far.

```
    class Account {

    private $connect; //sql connect
    private $errorArray; // Array to contain error messages

    public function __construct($connect) {

        $this->connect = $connect;
        $this->errorArray = array();

    }

    // VALIDATION FUNCTIONS, these functions are used to validate user input, things like password, email match
    public function register($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $cemail, $passwd, $cpasswd) {

        $this->validateUsername($uname);
        $this->validateFirstname($fname);
        $this->validateLastname($lname);
        $this->validateEmail($eml, $cemail);
        $this->validatePasswords($passwd, $cpasswd);

        if(empty($this->errorArray) == true) {// Check if array contain errors, if not insert data into db
            return insertUserDetails($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $passwd);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

AND here is the part the error come from I think

```
if(isset($_POST['register-button'])){   
//Get user info
$username = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username']);
$firstname = sanitizeFormString($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = sanitizeFormString($_POST['lastname']);
$email = sanitizeFormString($_POST['email']);
$confirmEmail = sanitizeFormString($_POST['confirmEmail']);
$password = sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['password']);
$confirmPassword = sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['confirmPassword']);

    //$wasSuccessful hold the result(value) of the function call (register);
$wasSuccessful = $account->register($username, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $confirmEmail, $password, $confirmPassword);

if($wasSuccessful == true) {
    header("Location: index.php"); //redirect user to index.php if successful.
}
```

}

Here is where I have included all the php code

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
include("includes/config.php");
include("includes/classes/Account.inc.php");
include("includes/classes/Constants.inc.php");

$account = new Account($connect); 

include("includes/handlers/register-handler.php");
include("includes/handlers/login-handler.php");

function getInputValue($name) {
    if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
        echo $_POST[$name];  
    }
}
```

?>

I try to replace the entire folder with the source code in case I typing error, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($this->errorArray) == true) {// Check if array contain errors, if not insert data into db
            return this-> insertUserDetails($uname, $fname, $lname, $eml, $passwd);
}
```

// this-> reference is necessary to insertuserdetails function

Comment: this -> reference is necessary

Answer (score -1):

After over a month of set back I figured out what was the problem after a series of tests.

There were an error in the sql statement bellow.

```
$result = mysqli_query($this->connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$uname', '$fname', '$lname', '$eml', '$encryptedPasswd', '$date', '$profilePic')");
```

When I execute the same statement directly in phpmyadmin I got an error saying that ID is incorrect so I replaced the empty string '' with '0' and it work.

I then did the same in the php code and everything work as expected now.

Comment: This wouldn't cause the error shown. `insertUserDetails` should be `$this->insertUserDetails` if it's part of the same class, or `$instance->insertUserDetails` if it's part of a class called `$instance`.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out, I did change    insertUserDetails to $this->InsertUserDetails it was the first error I saw but after that couldn't still insert data into mysql database. I guess I forgot about that part later. @ceejayoz